# Can I use a MySQL result from a Php PDO query in a Javascript Ajax table?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

So far I've built my website using Php, HTML, Bootstrap and CSS. I want to insert data from my Php database object (it fetches the result as an object as it's a database class using PDO). But I'm unsure how to carry the result array Into the scope of my JavaScript code for my AJAX table. Is this even possible or do I need to create my database functions in JavaScript as well? So far all tutorials I've seen involve creating a new script doc with all DB functions created procedurely when i want to take advantage of my database object.

```
<form action="" method="post">
        <dl>
            <dt>Procuct ID</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" name="Product" value="" /></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt>Price</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" name="Price" value="" /></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt>Description</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" name="Description" value="" /></dd>
        </dl>
        <h1>Parts</h1>
        <?php
        foreach($parts as $col) {
            ?>
            <dl>
                <dt><?php echo $col?></dt>
                <dd>
                    <select id="Brand" name="Brand">
                        <?php
                        $brand = $database->fetch_col($col);
                        $selected = false;
                        ?>
                        <option value="">Brand</option>
                        <?php foreach($brand as $b){ ?>
                            <option value="<?php $selected = true; ?>"><?php echo $b['Brand']; ?></option>
                        <?php }?>
                    </select>
                    <?php if($selected == true){
                        $item = $database->fetch_row($col, $b);
                        ?>
                        <select id="Model" name="Model">
                            <option value="">Model</option>
                            <?php foreach($item as $i) {?>
                                <option><?php echo $i['Model']; ?></option>
                            <?php }?>
                        </select>
                        <?php
                    } else {
                        echo "Please select Brand";
                    }
                    ?>
                    <select name="Quantity" id="Quantity">
                        <option value="">Quantity</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                    </select>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        <?php } ?>
        <dt>
            <div id="operations">
                <input type="submit" value="Create Product"/>
            </div>
        </dt>
    </form>
```

The form works really well the $parts array is defined at the top of the page eventually i'll create an autonomous array in a database, but for now i'm just keeping it simple.
So all Brands are successfully being called from the database, the only problem is once I've selected a brand I can not select a model hence why I asked about AJAX to be used here so I can fetch the model once Brand is selected. Any info is much appreciated as i'm still new to coding.

Comment: Sure it's possible, but the subject is way too broad to give a real answer. Your JS code would call a PHP script on your server. It would get the data and return it to your JS code, perhaps as JSON. Do some research on AJAX and JSON, then come back when you're stuck.

Comment: Aaah okay so I can't carry the variable with the result. I have to call the php function within the JavaScript code and assign it to a Javascript variable? @SloanT

Comment: Not exactly. You make an AJAX request to the PHP code on the server. Remember that JS runs in the browser, PHP runs on the server. Lookup "Javascript AJAX PHP".

Comment: Okay I will do. Thank you very much for your help and patience  @SloanT